# In Django how to compare two texts and print a message about correctness or error?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, django, django-views

I'm new to Django. In Django i would like to compare two texts, between frontend and backend, and receive a message if they are the same or different. In reality these two texts are two short HTML codes. The page can reload easily, I'm only interested in the logic and code behind comparing the two texts (and not the use of Ajax, jQuery, JS, but if it doesn't reload it's obviously better).

[image]

**INPUT USER.** A text will be inserted in the front-end by the user, in a black `div` (**no textarea**) with `contenteditable="true"` which is already present in my code. I have already prepared an example text in the black panel, so I would like to compare the entire block of html text (from `<!DOCTYPE html>` up to `</html>`). For several reasons i want to use a div, and not a textarea.

**TEXT TO COMPARE IN THE BACKEND.** While the other text will be contained in the backend (in a variable or something similar), and it will be the same html code (considering that the purpose is precisely comparison). I inserted the text to be compared into a variable named `corrected_text_backend`, but I don't know if it's a good idea, because in the future I would like to add conditions to the comparison, for example comparing only small parts of code (and not the entire code). So I would like to use a better way if it exists.

**COMPARISION RESULT.** Then i will click on the button and in the gray rectangle i would like to print `CORRECT: the two texts are the same` or `ERROR: the two texts are different`.

Important is that i don't want to use textarea, but as already said I want to use the div with contenteditable="true" that I already have in my code.

I'm having problems with the logic and code and can't proceed with the code in `views.py`. Can you help me and show me how? I'm new to Django, sorry.

**INDEX.HTML**

```
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>University</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href ="{% static 'css/styleparagone.css' %}" type="text/css">

</head>

<body>


  <div class="test">

    <div>Input User</div>
  
      <div class="hilite row">
  
        <pre class="hilite-colors"><code class="language-html"></code></pre>
        <div
             data-lang="html"
             class="hilite-editor"
             contenteditable="true"
             spellcheck="false"
             autocorrect="off"
             autocapitalize="off"
             >&lt;!DOCTYPE html>
&lt;html>
&lt;head>
&lt;title>Page Title&lt;/title>
&lt;/head>
&lt;body>     
             
&lt;h1 class="heading">This is a Heading&lt;/h1>   
&lt;p>This is a paragraph.&lt;/p>
    
&lt;/body>
&lt;/html></div>

  </div>
    
    <div>Comparison Result</div>
    <div class="result row2 rowstyle2"></div>
    
  </div> 

  <form action="{% url 'function_comparison' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}   
     <button type="submit" name='mybtn'>Button</button>
  </form>

  </div> 

<script src="{% static 'js/editor.js' %}"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

**EDITOR.JS**

```
/// CODE EDITOR ///

const elHTML = document.querySelector(`[data-lang="html"]`);
const elCSS = document.querySelector(`[data-lang="css"]`);
const elJS = document.querySelector(`[data-lang="js"]`);
const elPreview = document.querySelector("#preview");

const hilite = (el) => {
  const elCode = el.previousElementSibling.querySelector("code");
  elCode.textContent = el.textContent;
  delete elCode.dataset.highlighted;
  hljs.highlightElement(elCode);
};

const preview = () => {  
  const encodedCSS = encodeURIComponent(`<style>${elCSS.textContent}</style>`);
  const encodedHTML = encodeURIComponent(elHTML.textContent);
  const encodedJS = encodeURIComponent(`<scr` + `ipt>${elJS.textContent}</scr` + `ipt>`); 
  const dataURL = `data:text/html;charset=utf-8,${encodedCSS + encodedHTML + encodedJS}`;
  elPreview.src = dataURL;
};

// Initialize!

[elHTML, elCSS, elJS].forEach((el) => {
  el.addEventListener("input", () => {
    hilite(el);
    preview();
  });
  hilite(el);
});

preview();
```

**CSS**

```
.row {
    width: 500px;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 150px; /* Should be removed. Only for demonstration */
  }
  
  
  .rowstyle1 {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
  }
  
  .row2 {
    margin-top: 20px;
    width: 500px;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 15px; /* Should be removed. Only for demonstration */
  }
  
  
  .rowstyle2 {
    background-color: #ededed;;
    color: black;
  }
  
/******** CODE EDITOR CSS **********/  
/* Scrollbars */
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-radius: 0px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  border-radius: 1rem;
}


.hilite {
position: relative;
background: #1e1e1e;
height: 120px;
overflow: auto;
width: 500px;
height: 250px;
}

.hilite-colors code,
.hilite-editor {
padding: 1rem !important;
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
white-space: pre-wrap;
font: 13px/1.4 monospace;
width: 100%;
background: transparent;
border: 0;
outline: 0;
}

/* THE OVERLAYING CONTENTEDITABLE WITH TRANSPARENT TEXT */
.hilite-editor {
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
color: transparent; /* Make text invisible */
caret-color: hsl( 50, 75%, 70%); /* But keep caret visible */
width: 100%;
}


/* THE UNDERLAYING DIV WITH HIGHLIGHT COLORS */
.hilite-colors {
position: absolute;
user-select: none;
width: 100%;
color: white;
```

**MYAPP/URLS.PY**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from . import views as function_comparison

urlpatterns=[
  path('', views.index, name='index'), 
  path('function_comparison/', function_comparison,name="function_comparison"),
]
```

**PROJECT/URLS.PY**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('App1.urls')),
]
```

**MYAPP/VIEWS.PY**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
    """View function for home page of site."""
    return render(request, 'index.html')

def function_comparison(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        corrected_text_backend = """
             <!DOCTYPE html>
             <html>
             <head>
             <title>Page Title</title>
             </head>
             <body>     
         
             <h1 class="heading">This is a Heading</h1>   
             <p>This is a paragraph.</p>

             </body>
             </html>"""

             .....

        return render(request, "index.html")
```

Comment: Please try do reduce the amount of code to only what is relevant to your question.

Comment: Are you facing problem with collecting the user input?

Comment: @Jeppe If I'm wrong, I apologize, I'm new to Django. I thought I had already reduced to the maximum. Html, Css, views.py and the two urls.py are not good?

Comment: @shahriar Yes, too, but this and others

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so here is a working example of what i think you meant:
(There was a lot of stuff to change, which i will explain per section)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>University</title>

    <style>
      .row {
        width: 500px;
        padding: 10px;
        height: 150px; /* Should be removed. Only for demonstration */
      }
      
      
      .rowstyle1 {
        background-color: black;
        color: white;
      }
      
      .row2 {
        margin-top: 20px;
        width: 100%;
      }
      
      
      .rowstyle2 {
        background-color: #ededed;;
        color: black;
      }
      
      /******** CODE EDITOR CSS **********/  
      /* Scrollbars */
      ::-webkit-scrollbar {
        width: 5px;
        height: 5px;
      }
      
      ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
        border-radius: 0px;
      }
      
      ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
        background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
        border-radius: 1rem;
      }
      
      
      .hilite {
      position: relative;
      background: #1e1e1e;
      height: 120px;
      overflow: auto;
      width: 500px;
      height: 250px;
      }
      
      .hilite-colors code,
      .hilite-editor {
      padding: 1rem !important;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      white-space: pre-wrap;
      font: 13px/1.4 monospace;
      width: 100%;
      background: transparent;
      border: 0;
      outline: 0;
      }
      
      /* THE OVERLAYING CONTENTEDITABLE WITH TRANSPARENT TEXT */
      .hilite-editor {
      display: inline-block;
      position: relative;
      color: white;
      caret-color: hsl( 50, 75%, 70%); /* But keep caret visible */
      width: 100%;
      }
      
      
      /* THE UNDERLAYING DIV WITH HIGHLIGHT COLORS */
      .hilite-colors {
      position: absolute;
      user-select: none;
      width: 100%;
      color: white;
      }
    </style>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="test">

    <div>Input User</div> 
      <div class="hilite row">
  
        <pre class="hilite-colors"><code class="language-html"></code></pre>
        <div
            id="userinput"
            data-lang="html"
            class="hilite-editor"
            contenteditable="true"
            spellcheck="false"
            autocorrect="off"
            autocapitalize="off"
        >&lt;!DOCTYPE html>
        &lt;html>
        &lt;head>
        &lt;title>Page Title&lt;/title>
        &lt;/head>
        &lt;body>     
                     
        &lt;h1 class="heading">This is a Heading&lt;/h1>   
        &lt;p>This is a paragraph.&lt;/p>
            
        &lt;/body>
        &lt;/html>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div> 
      
    <button type="submit" onclick="getFormData();">Button</button>
  
    <br><br>
    <div>Comparison Result</div>
    <div class="result row2 rowstyle2" id="result">
      {% comment %} Ajax innerHTML result {% endcomment %}
    </div>
    
  </div> 

{% comment %} script to disable "want to send form again" popup {% endcomment %}
<script>
  if ( window.history.replaceState ) {
      window.history.replaceState( null, null, window.location.href );
  }
</script>

<script>
  function getFormData() {
      $.ajax({
          type:"GET",
          url: "{% url 'function_comparison' %}",
          data:{
              "formData": document.getElementById("userinput").innerText
          },
          success: function (response) {
              document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = response.message;
          },
          error: function (response) {
              console.log(response)
          }
      });
  }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Here I used AJAX to process the request, this allows us to collect the information which was previously in a form.

The reason I used AJAX was because you want to use a div instead of an input field (textarea), and if you send a form to the backend it expects input-field data, which we did not have. So now it collects the div-data and sends that as if you were sending a form.

After sending the AJAX request to `views.py`:

```py
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
import difflib
from django.conf import settings
import re

def index(request):
    return render(request, "index.html")

def function_comparison(request):
    context = {}
    if request.method == "GET":
        
        user_form_data = request.GET.get("formData", None)

        with open('user_input.html', 'w') as outfile:
            outfile.write(user_form_data)

        file1 = open('source_compare.html', 'r').readlines()
        file2 = open('user_input.html', 'r').readlines()

        file1_stripped = []
        file2_stripped = []

        for file1_text in file1:
            file1_text = re.sub("\s\s+", "", file1_text)
            file1_stripped.append(file1_text)

        for file2_text in file2:
            file2_text = re.sub("\s\s+", "", file2_text)
            file2_stripped.append(file2_text)
        # re sub here checks for each item in the list, and replace a space, or multiple space depending, with an empty string

        if file2_stripped[-1] == "":
            file2_stripped.pop()
        # check if the last item in the user input's list is an empty line with no additional text and remove it if thats the case.

        htmlDiffer = difflib.HtmlDiff(linejunk=difflib.IS_LINE_JUNK, charjunk=difflib.IS_CHARACTER_JUNK)
        htmldiffs = htmlDiffer.make_file(file1_stripped, file2_stripped, context=True)

        if "No Differences Found" in htmldiffs:
            context["message"] = "Yes, it is the same!"
        
        if settings.DEBUG:
            if "No Differences Found" not in htmldiffs:
                context["message"] = htmldiffs
        else:
            if "No Differences Found" not in htmldiffs:
                context["message"] = "No, it is not the same!"

    return JsonResponse(context, status=200)
```

Here the source_compare.html would look like this:
[image: source compare]

And the `user_input.html` is empty.

And that's it.

**Here are the results:**

If it is different:
[image: diffrenece]

If it is the same (where tabs, spaces and trailing and leading spaces don't matter):
[image: same]

You could tweak it to your liking to not show the left html, and only the right one in case of a difference, but that is up to preference.
More information on how to tweak the result can be found here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html

This is also a solution to what you said about wanting to compare only the `<head>` tag, because the difference html result will only show the parts that have changed.

---

EDIT 2:

To change if you want to show tables or text, you could check in your `views.py` if the setting `DEBUG` in your `settings.py` is set to `True` or `False`

See updated `views.py` above.

Comment: @Nodigap I just saw you are Dutch, to explain a bit more about Django, and especially the code you posted in this question, if you have any questions about it, or other Django related things, you can join this room: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256591/in-django-how-to-compare-two-texts-and-print-a-message-about-correctness 
in which we can speak in Dutch for an easier conversation while going a bit more off-topic

Comment: I'm trying to compare the html code of my question, but I always get the message "No, it is not the same". Strange. Can you try too and then maybe update your answer please? Maybe there's something wrong. I tried comparing the code both using "<" and using "&lt;"

Comment: P.S: Idea: What if instead of comparing the user input to the corrected_text_backend variable, we compared the user input to a simple txt file or something similar? This way there is no need for Regex for special characters. As also mentioned in the question, I didn't know if using a variable (corrected_text_backend) was the best solution (also considering that, as I said, in the future I would like to add conditions to the comparison, for example comparing only small parts of code and not the entire code)
​

Comment: Please see the chat room where i will explain more.

Comment: I also updated my answer as per your request. See **EDIT**

Comment: @Nodigap you could also try something more simple at first as your comparison isntead of a docstring, try using "Hello, World!" or something of the sort, so you at least know it works, how it works and what it's weak points are.

Comment: Probably because I forgot a part of the code, you couldn't compare the html and tried with a simple Hello Word. I apologize. I updated my code (css and js) and explained some things to you in chat, because in the question I specifically asked to compare HTML code, and then I asked not to use the variable to compare, but to use better ways than the variable. I invite you to read the chat where it explains better and change your answer please. I will be happy to vote and accept your answer in case of help. Thank you

Comment: I replied to you in chat :)

Comment: I wrote to you in chat. There is a small problem (a simple triviality, don't worry)